# Difference between Object.defineProperty and object property literal

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What difference ( if any ) is there between the `name` property of person and person2?

```
var person = function(){
    var _name;
    var _person = {};

    Object.defineProperties(_person, {
        name: {
            get: function(){ return _name },
            set: function(n) { _name = n; },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });

    return _person;
}();
person.name='john';
console.log(person.name);

function Person2()
{
    this.name = undefined;
}
var person2 = new Person2();
person2.name = 'john';
console.log(person2.name);
```

Comment: In this case none, because you have not defined any non-default configuration for the property...

Comment: Not true, a default for `defineProperties` is `writeable: false`, which means this attribute would no longer be changeable through the use of dot-notation. He would have to use the setter explicitly

Comment: Well, `person.name` is an accessor property (getter/setter) while `person2.name` is a data property. Isn't that obvious? For what differences are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

`defineProperties` simply gives you more power over the properties you define. If you use dot-notation to define a property as you did with Person2, that property is writeable, deletable, and enumerable by default.

You kept defaults for Person1, one of which is `writeable: false`, so you can't reassign the attribute unless you use the setter explicitly. In other words, you wouldn't be able to use dot-notation to change that attribute.

Generally there's not really a need for this behavior, so I'd be careful using it as it may cause unexpected results.

Comment: If you mean `person` (not `Person1`), it's `name` property does not have a writable attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Practical differences? Well:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(person, 'name')
```

will return a value that isn't equivalent to

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(person2, 'name')
```

Also these two function calls will have different effects:

```
Object.defineProperties(person, {name: {set: undefined}});
person.name; // john
Object.defineProperties(person2, {name: {set: undefined}});
person2.name; // undefined
```

But there aren't any especially significant differences, in my opinion,
if you're not messing with property descriptors.